# Issues with ADFS CRM to Sharepoint

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-2013, crm, adfs, adfs3.0

I have two applications, SharePoint and MS CRM that are external facing both configured with ADFS. Individually they work fine, but when I try and go from one app to the other I get issues. Going from Sharepoint to CRM is fine, but when I go to CRM to Sharepoint I get the ADFS login screen and when I login I get looped back to the login screen.

I have tried changing the relaying trust rules, configuring a sub domain for CRM, and just clearing the cookie on signout.

Answer (score 0):

I think SharePoint and CRM has to be in different Sub domains i.e there URL has to be different w.r.t sub domains.
Reason: share point and CRM both use different Authentication, One is Active and other is Passive.

Comment: Do make CRM like crm.crm.google.com ? Since the first CRM in the url is the org name

Comment: Yes you can try that

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same issue and its microsoft problem the token issued for crm doesnt work for sharepoint... we are using workaround with a link that is pointing to sharepoint and then redirecting to crm so that the token gets issued by sharepoint

Comment: Did you try the sub domain fix that ankuser mentioned?